# How to update model from database in ASP.NET MVC3 (Database First)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-database-first

I have two table like

[image]

Then I modify **ALLOCATION_M** table and add new table **EMP_INFO**. So I need to Update model from database as I modified and added table. I am trying it like following 
[image]

But the update wizard shows only **EMP_INFO** not the **ALLOCATION_M**

[image]

So, how can I update model(which table is modified) from database without deleting previous model?

Answer (score 0):

You can only add new tables from the `Add` tab. To Update tables that are already in your model, use the `Refresh` tab.